# Unconditionally disabling a function with SFINAE

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, overloading, sfinae

Is the following code valid? If it depends on the C++ version, I would also be interested in the corresponding differences (starting from C++14).

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

struct S {
    template< typename ... Args >
    void foo() const {
        static_assert( sizeof...(Args) == 0, "" );
    }

    template< typename ... Args, bool B = false, typename std::enable_if<B, bool>::type = false >
    void foo() {
        static_assert( sizeof...(Args) == 0, "" );
    }
};

int main() {
    S s{};
    s.foo();
}
```

I am asking because of the following things in the cpp standard (I do not know whether this is the actual version):

> The validity of a template may be checked prior to any instantiation.
>
> The program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required, if
> no valid specialization can be generated for a template or a substatement of a constexpr if statement within a template and the template is not instantiated, ...

My goal:  I am trying to remove the non-const version from overload resolution, when some macros are defined during compilation.

Comment: Maybe you need to rephrase your question : unconditionally disabling means always disabled :) So what do you want to do? Do you want the function to at least accept one argument? Because it really isn't clear what you want to do here.

Comment: "*Is the following code valid?*" - in what regard? What are you trying to accomplish with it, exactly?

Comment: In any case, the default `type` for `std::enable_if` is `void` not `bool`, so you would need to use either `typename std::enable_if<B>::type* = nullptr` or `typename std::enable_if<B, bool>::type = false` instead. Or, in C++14 and later, you can drop the `typename` if you use `std::enable_if_t`, eg: `std::enable_if_t<B>* = nullptr` or `std::enable_if_t<B, bool> = false`

Comment: If disabled by macros, wouldn't `#if !defined some_macros` be involved, instead of `enable_if`?

Comment: You're currently running afoul of [[temp.res.general]/6.3](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.res.general#6.3); both of your `foo` templates are ill-formed NDR. You need to show a more realistic example AND show how you intend to use the macro.